# How to run service with deploy.replica=0 in docker-compose.yml?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, containers

I have services in my `docker-compose.yml` configuration that I would occasionally use, such as for end-to-end testing, linting, or some one-off service.

Something along the lines of this:

```
  app:
    ...

  e2e-or-linter-or-one-off:
    ...
    deploy:
      replicas: 0
```

With `replicas` set to 0, `docker-compose up` would not spin up the `e2e-or-linter-or-one-off` service when I just want to run my regular app container(s).

And when I would need that `e2e-or-linter-or-one-off` service, I want to do something like this:

```
docker-compose run e2e-or-linter-or-one-off bash
```

Is there a way to define a service that doesn't spin up on `docker-compose up` but is still able to be used with `docker-compose run`?

`docker-compose up` has a `--scale` flag that I can use if I wanted to spin everything up, such as:

```
docker-compose up --scale "e2e-or-linter-or-one-off"=1 e2e-or-linter-or-one-off
```

But `docker-compose run` doesn't have a similar flag that can be used and I need `docker-compose run` so I can run the container interactively.  Without it this:

```
docker-compose run e2e bash
```

won't work and Docker returns: `no containers to start`

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This article](https://karuppiah7890.github.io/blog/posts/optionally-running-services-in-docker-compose/) shows a way to use an environment variable for the replica count, allowing you to change the value at invocation-time:

```yaml
  app:
    ...

  e2e-or-linter-or-one-off:
    ...
    deploy:
      replicas: ${E2E_REPLICAS:-0}
```

I modified the example a bit so you don't need to have the env var set 100% of the time. The `:-` in the variable expansion is an operator that says "use the default value to the right if the name to the left is unset or empty".

Now running `docker-compose up` should run every service with 1+ replicas defined, but invoking `E2E_REPLICAS=1 docker-compose run --rm e2e-or-linter-or-one-off bash` will set the env variable, overriding the default value of `0`, create the container & service, and run `bash`. When you're done with your shell session, the `--rm` tag will tear down the container so the environment returns to its normal operational state.

Comment: Thanks for the info and links.  I ended up using `profiles` as it was a better fit for my use case: https://docs.docker.com/compose/profiles/
Thanks again 